# echo inside a while loop not displaying data in real time. The display happens at the end only

Tags: php

I have this simple code

```
 echo "start<br>";

 while($row = $stmt->fetch())
 { 
    // code
    echo "inside while<br>";
 }

  echo "done";
```

The page doesn't echo my inside in real time, Once it's done processing the entire data, then it outputs all the echo at the same time..  I would like to see the echo inside while as they happen, one after the other...

thanks

Comment: Does it maybe happen so fast that you can't see it echo one by one? Use dial-up, maybe then you'll see it happening in "real-time"

Comment: Unless you have a really large amount of records, all this will happen in mere millseconds … so there isn’t much to see, even if it wasn’t for the different buffers that might be at play here (PHP output buffer, web server buffer, browser waiting for a certain amount of data before starting to render stuff …)

Comment: no, it takes some time... about 20 sec. to process the data in the page...

Comment: As mentioned above: it may be too fast. Toss a sleep() function in there and see what happens then.

Comment: How many times does it loop? If it isn't enough to go past the bottom of the page, you won't see it load in real-time. Try a for-loop that an echo 1 - 1,000,000 with a `<br/>`, then you may see it.

Comment: Well if processing the individual records really takes a significant amount of time, then there’s still the buffers that come into play. Flushing PHP’s buffer would be the first step … this has been discussed already, so please do some research on this.

Comment: Why was this question closed...seems perfectly valid to me.... and Rocket's answer below works.

Answer (score 5):

That's how PHP works by default.  It buffers the output and won't send it to your browser until the page is complete.

There is a way around it.  You turn off all output buffering and you tell PHP to `flush` the data every time you `echo`.

I found a solution here: http://manzzup.blogspot.com/2013/11/real-time-updating-of-php-output-using.html

The code to do this is:

```
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
while(@ob_end_flush());

// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);

// Needed to force browsers to actually display data
echo str_pad("",1024," ");
echo "<br />";
```

Add this to the top of your page.  Then your data will display on the page *as* the loop is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with php easily. Your data is only sent to the browser when it is ready, meaning that your script needs to finish before anything is sent.

If you still wanna have real-time data, you'll have to use `JavaScript` and `Ajax`, our you modify some php settings, as proposed in the other answers.

Comment: using `echo` doesn't really send anything to the server, it just spits out HTML onto the page.

Comment: @TimLewis Despite the fact I never said that, php is running ON the server. Php never sends sth. to a Server. But what echo does is sending data to the Client - aka the Browser.

Comment: I'd love to know why I got those down votes...

Comment: I didn't downvote just fyi and I know php runs on the server, all I meant was this example isn't really sending anything.

Comment: @TimLewis echo is putting content into HTML. And the HTML is then sent to the browser - if it wouldn't do that, the echoed content would never be visible anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It's likely output buffering. You can try something like this:

```
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start(); 
echo "start<br>";
ob_flush(); 
flush();  

 while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
    echo "inside while<br>";
    ob_flush(); 
    flush();  
    usleep(50000);//flush wait for IE
 }

echo "done";
ob_flush(); 
flush();
```

Comment: that didn't change anything....

Comment: Probably need to add the ini settings like in Rocket's answer

Answer (score 0):

As others say, PHP shows the content after is loaded. If there are too much content, then would happen as you say, but that's not often the case.

That said, if you like the effect, you can write some javascript to simulate it:

```js
var rows = $(".rows").find("p");

var delay = 0;
rows.each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        row.slideDown();
        $("body")[0].scrollTop = $("body")[0].scrollHeight;
    }, delay);
    delay += 500;
});
```

```css
#content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
.rows p {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Database rows</h1>
    <div class="rows">
        <p>Database row #1</p>
        <p>Database row #2</p>
        <p>Database row #3</p>
        <p>Database row #4</p>
        <p>Database row #5</p>
        <p>Database row #6</p>
        <p>Database row #7</p>
        <p>Database row #8</p>
        <p>Database row #9</p>
        <p>Database row #10</p>
        <p>Database row #11</p>
        <p>Database row #12</p>
        <p>Database row #13</p>
        <p>Database row #14</p>
        <p>Database row #15</p>
        <p>Database row #16</p>
        <p>Database row #17</p>
        <p>Database row #18</p>
        <p>Database row #19</p>
        <p>Database row #20</p>
        <p>Database row #21</p>
        <p>Database row #22</p>
        <p>Database row #23</p>
        <p>Database row #24</p>
        <p>Database row #25</p>
    </div>
</div>
```